# Why is the complexity of the function f(n) = n^d, O(b^n), where b>1 and d is positive?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

So, I came across this problem in my book of discrete mathematics where it says, the complexity of the function `f(n) = n^d` is `O(b^n)`, where `b>1` and `d` is positive. But I cant seem to understand why. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: i'm not sure but f(n) =n^2  is O (2^n ) .. not possible.. it will be O (n^2).
which book ? author ?

Comment: @Cereal_Killer Yes, it's possible. O(2^n) is a superset of O(n^2).

Comment: my bad! misunderstood... Thanks xszaboj for the answer. it's about finding the upper bound and it will never be larger than `b^n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `L = lim{n->inf} (n^d/b^n) 
 => ln(L) = lim{n->inf} (d*ln(n) / (n*ln(b))) 
          = (d/ln(b)) * lim{n->inf} (ln(n) / n) = (inf) / (inf)
          = (d/ln(b)) * lim{n->inf} (d/dn(ln(n)) / d/dn(n))` (apply `L-Hospital`)

```
      = (d/ln(b)) * lim{n->inf} (1/n) / (1) = (d/ln(b)) * 0 = 0
```

(since `b>1`, `ln(b) > 0`)

`=> L = exp(0) = 1 < inf`

Since `lim{n->inf} (n^d/b^n) < inf`, we can say that `n^d=O(b^n)` when `b>1` (refer to this for alternative definition of `O`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

The gist is that `exponential` function grows faster than `polynomials`.

Answer (score 0):

Example:
d = 2

f(2) = 4, f(3) = 9, f(4) = 16 ....

for:
d = 3

f(2) = 8, f(3) = 21, f(4) = 64 ...
.
.
.

so as long as n>1 (you are saying b, but it is n) and d is positive
time complexity will be O(n^d)

Also here you can see what is the growth of function
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to come up with an alternative solution to that of @Sandipan Dey's. Since b > 1 and d > 0, b ^ ( 1 / d ) > 1. So, log<sub>b<sup>(1/d)</sup></sub>(n) < n.
It follows that,

```
  => log n / log (b^(1/d)) < n
  => d*logn < d*n*log (b^(1/d))
  => log (n^d) < log (b^((1/d)*n*d)))
  => n^d <= b^n
```

which proves that n^d is of O( b^n ).